# Making a cursor for use in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, matrixcursor

What I am trying to accomplish here is to make a `Cursor` that could be used in an android `ListView`. I'm reading values directly from multiple files and have to feed them to the cursor. I tried to use `MatrixCursor` but I can't get it to work with arrays. I have posted my attempt at it so far below and I'm open to all new suggestions. Is there a simpler way to do this?

```
static MatrixCursor getnameList() {
        ArrayList<String> fsitem = getfsiList();
        MatrixCursor cursor;
        cursor = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < fsitem.size(); i++) {
            try {
                File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getName() + "/" + fsitem.get(i));
                if (root.canRead()) {
                    File namefile = new File(root, ".name");
                    FileReader namereader = new FileReader(namefile);
                    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(namereader);
                    String name = in.readLine();
                    String id = in.readLine();
                    String info = in.readLine();
                    String[] fsii = new String[3];
                    fsii[0]= name;
                    fsii[1]= id;
                    fsii[2]= info;
                    cursor.addRow(fsii); //crashes here on running.
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("NameManager.java : ", ("Error!! Not Writable!!"
                        + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getName()
                        + "/" + fsitem.get(i)));
            }
        }
```

This code compiles but crashes at `cursor.addRow(fsii);`:

`with 02-24 21:16:49.589: E/AndroidRuntime(3895):  at com.manager.abcd.r1223.NameManager.getnameList(NameManager.java:81)`.

I'm thinking this is a problem with `MartixCursor` not supporting arrays, but I might be wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is all the code then it is normal because you try to add a row on a null cursor(you never initialize `cursor`) and probably get a `NullPointerException`.
Initialize the `MatrixCursor` before you enter in the for loop:

```
String[] columnNames = {"col1", "col2", "col3"};
MatrixCursor cursor = new MatrixCursor(columnNames);
```

Check the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).

Comment: `cursor = new MatrixCursor;` ?

Comment: But here `cursor.getString(0)` gives an outofbounds exception. Is the structure of the cursor valid?

Comment: @BinoyBabu Are you sure that you actually insert something in the cursor in that foor loop?

Comment: @BinoyBabu Also before the line `cursor.getString(0)` call `cursor.moveToNext()` your ursor is at position -1, this may be a cause for the `OutOfBoundException`.

Comment: `cursor.moveToNext()` fixed it. Thanks